# Changing name of sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, instance-variables

I am working on a program in which I want to create more than one SQLite database.  I have written an activity in which the user can choose the name of the database, but I am having trouble sending that name to the activity which opens the database.

I have been learning Android programming from the Big Nerd Ranch Guide, and since I want to store lists of items, I have started with the criminalIntent program from that book.

To choose the name of the SQLite database, I have created another database containing a list of database names.  The user pushes a button to choose the name, but then I want to open the SQLite database with that name in another activity.

My approach is as follows: (code shown at end of message)  The user picks the name of the SQLite database in DataSetListFragment, then the database is opened in InstructLab (which is almost the same as CrimeLab in CriminalIntent).  I declared a variable sScheduleName, which is the name of the SQLite database.  First in DataSetListFragment, I try to assign the name of the database using an InstructLab setter method.  Then when I create an instance of InstructLab, the sScheduleName is null.

I have tried other ideas.  I use putExtra to return the name of the database to the Main Activity.  From the MainActivity, the user chooses another activity which will list the contents of the SQLite database with the name returned in the putExtra.  However, there is several layers of code before the name of the SQLite database is used and I do not know how to send the name using putExtra and then retrieving it at the location in the code where I need it.

I am not really sure what approach to take so that I can get the information about the name of the database from DataSetListFragment to the InstructLab instance when the database is opened, so could someone please point me in the correct direction?

Thanks.

public class DataSetListFragment extends Fragment {

```
private String mCurrentFile;

    public DataSetHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_dataset_info);
        mNameButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.choose_schedule_name);
        mNameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
                DataSetLab.get(getActivity()).setCurrentData(mTitleTextView.getText().toString());
                InstructLab.get(getActivity()).setScheduleName(mTitleTextView.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "send back to MainActivity: "+mTitleTextView.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME,mTitleTextView.getText().toString());
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
                getActivity().finish();

            }
        });
    }
```

}

public class InstructLab {
    private static InstructLab sInstructLab;

```
private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
private static String sScheduleName;

public String getScheduleName() {
    return sScheduleName;
}

public void setScheduleName(String scheduleName) {
    this.sScheduleName = scheduleName;
    Log.d(TAG,"Assigning database name:"+sScheduleName);
}



public static InstructLab get(Context context) {
    if (sInstructLab == null) {

        sInstructLab = new InstructLab(context);
    }
    return sInstructLab;
}

private InstructLab(Context context) {
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    Log.d(TAG,"Opening Database "+sScheduleName);
    mDatabase = new InstructBaseHelper(mContext,sScheduleName).getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d(TAG,"Opening Database "+sScheduleName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fragment is a view group on Activity, You do not need to use setresult to update your Activity. You can just use an interface to communicate with Activity.

```
public class DataSetListFragment extends Fragment {

    private String mCurrentFile;

    public DataSetHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_dataset_info);
        mNameButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.choose_schedule_name);
        mNameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {                
                ((YourActivity)getActivity()).onDataSetLab(DataSetLab.get(getActivity()).setCurrentData(mTitleTextView.getText().toString()));
                ((YourActivity)getActivity()).onInstructLab(InstructLab.get(getActivity()).setScheduleName(mTitleTextView.getText().toString()));              

            }
        });
    }

    public interface  DBNameListener {
        public void onDataSetLab(String name);
        public void onInstructLab(String name);
    }

}
```

**Then, In your Activity, Just implements DBNameListener,**

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements DatasetListFragment.DBNameListener {

@Override
public void onDataSetLab(String name) {
 // do your stuff 
}

@Override
public void onInstructLab(String name) {
 // do your stuff 
}
}
```